# Как в handlebars вставить один partial в другой?

Tags: handlebars

```
{{> "body"}}
 {{> "content"}}
{{/"body"}}
```

Где шаблон body имеет код

```
<div>
{{{this}}} // сюда будет вставлено {{> "content"}} то есть шаблон content
</div>
```